# Class redeclaration error on targetEntity="Y" within ZF2

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, autoload

I am facing a weird error within my codebase currently. You can see the full ZF2s project code on [my github right here](https://github.com/manuakasam/webkennzahlen/blob/master/module/Kennzahlen/src/Kennzahlen/Controller/SteuerController.php#L9). <- there's a link

I'm having a Module set up with two Entities (X and Y). Entity_X contains a reference to Entity_Y via (targetEntity="Entity_Y"). The Error persist with the FQCN or just the CN itself.

```
Entity_X:
  id int PK,
  id_Y int FK,
  text varchar

Entity_Y:
  id int PK,
  text varchar
```

When loading Entity_Y first and then Entity_X everything is working fine. This remains true for both StandardAutoloader and ClassMapAutoloader. **However**: when loading Entity_X first with ClassMapAutoloader present, i will be seeing the following error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Kennzahlen\Entity\Referenzwert (Entity_Y)
in \module\Kennzahlen\src\Kennzahlen\Entity\Referenzwert.php 
on line 13
```

Loading Entity_X first with StandardAutoloader works without any problems, too.

**Update**

The Problem appears to be within ZF2s ClassMapAutoloader (or Autoloading-Mechanism in General). My Module used the ClassMapAutoloader and using this i've gotten the above mentioned error. When removing the ClassMapAutoloader and simply using the StandardAutoloader, the error vanished into thin air. Thanks to @ocramius and all others i've botheres with this :)

Comment: I'm having the same issue, except it only appears when I attempt to load an entity from a CLI controller action.  Calling the same mapper method from a HTTP controller action works fine.  https://gist.github.com/017c56ac2ae7553a7ca5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have no knowledge of doctrine, but i browsed through source and i think i found issue:
https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php#L224
here, this code expects that autoloader will return value evaluated to true, but that is not requirement of spl autoload mechanism, therefore autoloader can return NULL,

To check if i am correct, in in your project in doctrine replace line 224 in `Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php`

```
} else if ($loader[0]->{$loader[1]}($className)) {
```

with

```
} else if ($loader[0]->{$loader[1]}($className) && class_exists($className, false)) {
```

Ans see if issue is fixed, if i am correct - then report bug to doctrine project

Comment: i don't understand why they looping through registred autoloaders at all. `class_exists($NAME, TRUE)` should be enough

Comment: Since the problem is related with DoctrineORMModule (and I don't think we use Doctrine's classloader anywhere) I don't think this is the right way...

Comment: @Ocramius, as discussed in irc: issue is within classExists() utility method of ClassLoader, which invokes registered autoloaders

Comment: Errata, see my answer... Xerkus has actually drilled out the problem :)

Comment: Thanks to you, too! Since you pretty much boiled it down to the autoloading i've given you the accepted answer, even ic @Ocramius explained in details where the error comes from, kudos to both of you! Excitedly waiting for a patch now, since the ClassMapAutoloader boosts performance by roughly 40% in my case :D

Comment: you can use composer's classmap generator by calling `composer.phar dump-autoload --optimize`

Answer (score 4):

I'm writing a failing test case to try and solve this in [doctrine/common](https://github.com/doctrine/common). The problem seems to be that silent autoloaders (as explained by @Xerkus) are not compatible with doctrine/common itself. To solve that, use a `StandardAutoloader` from ZF2 (or from composer) instead of using the `ClassMapAutoloader`. This will solve the issue until a patch is ready.

Update: patch is being suggested at [doctrine/common#216](https://github.com/doctrine/common/pull/216)

Comment: I applied your commits to my local clone and it fixed the issue.  Thanks to you and Xerkus for troubleshooting this!